# What's the point of assignment to slice?

Tags: python

I found this line in the pip source:

```
sys.path[:] = glob.glob(os.path.join(WHEEL_DIR, "*.whl")) + sys.path
```

As I understand the line above is doing the same as below:

```
sys.path = glob.glob(os.path.join(WHEEL_DIR, "*.whl")) + sys.path
```

With one difference: in the first case `sys.path` still points to the same object in memory while in the second case `sys.path` points to the new list created from two existing.

Another one thing is that the first case is two times slower than second:

```
>>> timeit('a[:] = a + [1,2]', setup='a=[]', number=20000)
2.111023200035561
>>> timeit('a = a + [1,2]', setup='a=[]', number=20000)
1.0290934000513516
```

The reason as I think is that in the case of slice assignment objects from `a` (references to objects) are copied to a new list and then copied back to the resized `a`.

So what are the benefits of using a slice assignment?

Answer (score 5):

Assigning to a slice is useful if there are other references to the same list, and you want all references to pick up the changes.

So if you do something like:

```
bar = [1, 2, 3]
foo = bar
bar[:] = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
print(foo)
```

this will print `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`. If you instead do:

```
bar = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
print(foo)
```

the output will be `[1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: So it is a safe way to change sys.path in case if somewhere there is another variable for example `my_name = sys.path` and the developer didn't expect that sys.path may be reassigned. And also it is a short way to insert several items in the begining of the list.

Comment: It really depends on the application -- do you want the changes to be reflected in all references or not? Sometimes you get bugs because you have multiple references when you really wanted copies. So it all depends on what you intend.

Comment: This simply gives you flexibility to do it either way.

Answer (score 3):

> With one difference: in the first case `sys.path` still points to the same object in memory while in the second case `sys.path` points to the new list created from two existing.

Right: That’s the whole point, you’re modifying the object behind the name instead of the name. Thus all other names referring to the same object also see the changes.

> Another one thing is that the first case is two times slower than second:

Not really. Slice assignment performs a copy. Performing a copy is an O(n) operation while performing a name assignment is O(1). In other words, the bigger the list, the slower the copy; whereas the name assignment always takes the same (short) time.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumptions are very good!

In python a variable is a name that has been set to point to an object in memory, which in essence is what gives python the ability to be a dynamically typed language, i.e. you can have the same variable as a number, then reassign it to a string etc.

as shown here whenever you assign a new value to a variable, you are just pointing a name to a different object in memory

```
>>> a = 1
>>> id(a)
10968800
>>> a = 1.0
>>> id(a)
140319774806136
>>> a = 'hello world'
>>> id(a)
140319773005552
```

(in CPython the `id` refers to its address in memory).

Now for your question `sys.path` is a `list`, and a python `list` is a mutable type, thus meaning that the type itself can change, i.e.

```
>>> l = []
>>> id(l)
140319772970184
>>> l.append(1)
>>> id(l)
140319772970184
>>> l.append(2)
>>> id(l)
140319772970184
```

even though I modified the list by adding items, the `list` still points to the same object, and following the nature of python, a lists elements as well are only pointers to different areas in memory (the elements aren't the objects, the are only like variables to the objects held there) as shown here,

```
>>> l
[1, 2]
>>> id(l[0])
10968800
>>> l[0] = 3
>>> id(l[0])
10968864
>>> id(l)
140319772970184
```

After reassigning to `l[0]` the id of that element has changed. but once again the list hasn't.

Seeing that assigning to an index in the list only changes the places where lists elements where pointing, now you will understand that when I reassign `l` I don't reassign, I just change where `l` was pointing

```
>>> id(l)
140319772970184
>>> l = [4, 5, 6]
>>> id(l)
140319765766728
```

but if I reassign to all of `l`s indexes, then `l` stays the same object only the elements point to different places

```
>>> id(l)
140319765766728
>>> l[:] = [7, 8, 9]
>>> id(l)
140319765766728
```

That will also give you understanding on why it is slower, as python is reassigning the elements of the list, and not just pointing the list somewhere else.

One more little point if you are wondering about the part where the line finishes with

```
sys.path[:] = ... + sys.path
```

it goes in the same concept, python first creates the object on the right side of the `=` and then points the name on the left side to the new object, so when python is still creating the new list on the right side, `sys.path` is in essence the original list, and python takes all of its elements and then reassigns all of the newly created elements to the mappings in the original `sys.path`s addresses (since we used `[:]`)

now for why pip is using `[:]` instead of reassigning, I don't really know, but I would believe that it might have a benefit of reusing the same object in memory for `sys.path`.
python itself also does it for the small integers, for example

```
>>> id(a)
10968800
>>> id(b)
10968800
>>> id(c)
10968800
```

`a`, `b` and `c` all point to the same object in memory even though all requested to create an `1` and point to it, since python knows that the small numbers are most probably going to be used a lot in programs (for example in `for` loops) so they create it and reuse it throughout.
(you might also find it being the case with filehandles that python will recycle instead of creating a new one.)

Answer (score 0):

You are right, slice assignment will not rebind, and `slice object` is one type of objects in Python. You can use it to set and get.

```
In [1]: a = [1, 2, 3, 4]

In [2]: a[slice(0, len(a), 2)]
Out[2]: [1, 3]

In [3]: a[slice(0, len(a), 2)] = 6, 6

In [4]: a[slice(0, len(a), 1)] = range(10)

In [5]: a
Out[5]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In [6]: a[:] = range(4)

In [7]: a
Out[7]: [0, 1, 2, 3]
```